# How do I break a boat into pieces while making sure it doesn't look broken before?

Tags: objects

I've tried using the cell fracture add-on but the boat looks all messed up. I tried hiding the cell fracture and then showing it when I wanted it to break but apparently I can't animate viewing on collections. [image: This is what the boat looks like after cell fracture.]

[image]

Comment: I encountered this with a star ship. I’ll get you the script, but basically what it did was adding drivers to all of the pieces’ visibility, and I think linking them to the main ship’s visibility.

Comment: @shrub: can you do it successfully with the default cube? if yes, pls try the same settings with your boat. If no, pls show us you settings of your cell fracture

Comment: You can use the collection as an instance and make the instance invisible then visible as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WshXRndeOM ... As for the boat looking messed up it may have something to do with the rigid body setup?

Comment: @Chris, it works perfectly on cube.

Comment: @TheLabCat, sorry I'm quite new to blender, can u please explain what you mean.

Comment: @moonboots thank you, that video looks helpful, will definitely try.

Comment: @shrub it means I wrote a program to set up all the shattered pieces so they would appear as soon as the unshattered ship disappeared, and also enable their physics. I will try to get you the script. It’s somewhere on my hard drive.

Comment: @TheLabCat thanks, have you found it yet, need it for a school project.

Comment: @shrub Forgot all about it. Don’t count on me. I would get it now, but I’ve got one computer to work with, and it’s shared at the moment.

Comment: @TheLabCat, no worries. Didn't really need it anyway, the teacher doesn't expect much. However, I tried rendering it and my ocean is showing up as a solid colour in the render even thought it looks textured in the shading tab. What's wrong?

Comment: @TheLabCat couldn't add image to comment so added it to question.

Comment: @shrub that’s a separate question, and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to set up drivers on all the shattered pieces, to enable rigid body physics and show them in the render when a certain property of an empty (or any) object turns True.

Set up an empty named REF_OBJ and a variable accessed by DAT_PATH (in this case a custom property called "Explosion On") that turns True when the shattered pieces need to appear. Select all the shatter pieces in the viewport (but NOTHING else), and run this script. I recommend you also manually set up a driver the un-shattered boat to disappear based on the same REF_OBJ, DAT_PATH property.

```
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

REF_OBJ=bpy.data.objects["Explosion Point"]
DAT_PATH="[\"Explosion On\"]"

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    rd=o.driver_add("hide_render").driver
    pd=o.driver_add("rigid_body.kinematic").driver
    
    for d in (rd, pd):
        v=d.variables.new()
        v.targets[0].id=REF_OBJ
        v.targets[0].data_path=DAT_PATH
    rd.expression="not var"
    pd.expression="not var"
```